# Как сделать постраничную навигацию WordPress?

Tags: wordpress

Хочу сделать постраничную навигацию при выборе рубрики:

```
cx80363-wordpress.tw1.ru/category/toys/
```

Примерный код, работающий на `category.php`:

```
<?php query_posts(array(
'cat' => 1,
'paged' => 1,
'post_per_page' => '1'
));

if ( have_posts() ) while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
/* Посты */
<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php the_posts_pagination(); ?>
```

Саму навигацию по страницам выводит, но при попытке перейти ничего не происходит.
Что я делаю не так?
WP 4.9.2
Шаблон самописный.

Answer (score 0):

Не так ты делаешь только одно, ты берешь и выводить просто все посты. При переходе в навигации, ты передаешь номер страницы, чтоб получить первый пост, который надо вывести на странице, надо умножить номер страницы, на количество постов, которые должны отображаться на странице. Таким образом выводишь нужное количество постов начиная с текущего. Делается это циклом

```
for($i=$page*$postPerPage; $i<$page*$postPerPage+$postPerPage; $i++) 
  printPost($i);
```

Чтоб это реализовать тебе надо понимать что такое циклы, массивы и как с ними работать.

Comment: `$page*$postPerPage` - никогда такое в циклах не пишите, так пых делает просчеты на каждой итерации

Comment: Ну и пусть делает, это мелочь.